# When did USPS stop shipping its TIGER/ZIP+4 product?

Tags: data, united-states, zip-codes, zip4

When did USPS stop producing its TIGER/ZIP+4 dataset?

Updates to the product page [archived by the WayBack Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20011106042019/http://www.usps.com/ncsc/addressmgmt/tiger.htm) stopped in July 2011, but it looks like some people might have been using it later than that.

I'm trying to figure out the range of years this product would cover if I could get a hold of the old CDs and DVDs.

Unfortunately, the support team for this data product no longer exists.

Comment: If this is open data then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Sure, why not both? Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Cross-posted as https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/19976/when-did-usps-start-stop-producing-its-tiger-zip4-dataset

Answer (score 0):

I reached the USPS team that used to produce this product. They said they discarded their archives, and the product was discontinued around 2011 because (1) the underlying Census data never seemed to change, and (2) about half of their ZIP+4 codes couldn't be attached to any feature in the Census TIGER files. I also reached Census folks who said Census had nothing to do with this product, and they had a low opinion of it. Dead end.